# Weird behaviour on Numeric Stepper decimals

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, numbers, decimal, numericupdown

I am making an editor for a field with numbers. I tried a text field, but since it's a Number datatype coming in, it didn't go smoothly -- despite recasting strings as numbers etc.. it kept giving me NaN as the value. So I decided it would be best to go with a numeric stepper.

When I initially loaded it up it would drop all my decimals and only display my numbers as integers.  I changed the stepIncrement to 0.1 and now it does show the decimals (a weird requirement imo).. but when I step up it occasionally gives me a value like '17.700000000000003' when I would expect 17.7.  All of the numbers in my data have a single decimal place. I know I can write a dataformatter, but it seems like it shouldn't be necessary in this situation.

Is there another way I could deal with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've stumbled upon the compromise of trying to represent decimal numbers in floating point binary formats like IEEE 754. Not all decimal numbers can be exactly represented. You can read up on this issue in great detail here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

You can use **Number.toFixed(fractionDigits:uint)** to display to an arbitrary number of decimal places.

Comment: ah!  unfortunately toFixed is a string value and I need number input and output from my database. I tried `.toFixed(1) as Number` but it just ends up as 0.1 no matter the value..

Comment: That sounds feasible. I'm not a Flex framework user, but a quick perusal of the component description makes me think you could probably dynamically manipulate the maxChars property of the textField (TextInput) of the stepper to hide the inexactness. Set maxChars to the number of digits of your number rounded to an integer, plus 1. If you still want to support typing in of numbers manually, that could get a bit hacky (like if you have to remove the restriction on focus).

Comment: very logical! unfortunately it turns out maxChars is the number of characters "you" can enter, not the number of characters that can be displayed...

Comment: Dang it. I should have read further. Adobe's description of maxChars starts off hopeful, then delivers that bad news: "maxChars property; indicates the maximum number of characters that the text field can contain. A script may insert more text than maxChars allows; the maxChars property only indicates how much text a user can enter."

Comment: OK then, how about this: manually set myNumericStepper.textField.text in an Event.CHANGE listener, replacing the inexact crap that is there with myNumericStepper.value.toFixed(1) My last hope of helping... :-)

Comment: beautiful. i missed the textDisplay.text business looking through the documentation, but it def stands to reason it'd be there. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the valueFormatFunction which takes the numeric value and formats it to a string. You will need to set explicit widths on your numeric steppers to make they fit though.

Answer (score 0):

in your MXML

```
<s:NumericStepper  valueFormatFunction="stepperFormatter"/>
```

in your script

```
protected function stepperFormatter(newValue:Number):String
{
    return Math.ceil(newValue).toString()
}
```